# System.NullPointerException: Argument 2 cannot be null

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to pick up all of the text field (Description__c )value from an object (National__c) and display those text values as a picklist in a visual force page. However I am facing an error -  Argument 2 cannot be null.

Could you please help. Below are the code piece. getTypeOptions() is called from the controller.

```
      <apex:selectList id="description" value="{!s.Description__c}"  size="1" required="true">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeOptions}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
```

Controller -

```
 public List<SelectOption> getTypeOptions(){
       List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
       options.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));

       for (National__c obj2 : [SELECT Id,Description__c FROM National__c]) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(obj2.Id, obj2.Description__c));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before you populate the options in loop , put a null pointer check like :
if(obj2.Description__c != null) then add options.add(new SelectOption(obj2.Id, obj2.Description__c));