# Trying to create a trigger that will for the query the name from another object then get its ID

Tags: trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger that will search in Object **RecognitionPeriod** using its name(FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule) then get the ID(of RecognitionPeriod).

```
trigger OppLineItemScheduleTrigger on OpportunityLineItemSchedule (after insert) {
    Set<String>Name = new Set<String>();
    
    for(OpportunityLineItemSchedule Sch:Trigger.New){
        Name.add(sch.Period_Name__c);
    }
    
    Set<Id>Names = new Set<Id>([SELECT Id FROM ffrr__RecognitionPeriod__c
                                        WHERE Name IN: Name]);
    
    for(OpportunityLineItemSchedule olis: trigger.new){
        ffrr__RecognitionPeriod__c prd = Names.get(olis.Period_Name__c);
        olis.Recognition_Period__c = prd.Id;
    }
}
```

I'm having a *Argument 2 cannot be null* error in the debug logs.

Please let me know what I'm missing, specially the best practices that I'm missing.

Thank you

Comment: First off there is no get method in Set. Also it should be  List<Account>Names = new List<Account>([SELECT Id FROM ffrr__RecognitionPeriod__c
                                        WHERE Name IN: Name]);

Comment: The code is also missing a null pointer check. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63553/system-nullpointerexception-argument-2-cannot-be-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this code should not compile because of these reasons.

1. `Set<Id>Names = new Set<Id>([SELECT Id FROM ffrr__RecognitionPeriod__c WHERE Name IN: Name]);` as there is no return type or type case to Set from SOQL.
2. `Names.get(olis.Period_Name__c);` there is no `get` method in `Set` like the way you are using it. The method is in `Map`.

Also as this is `after insert` context, I dont think the code will ever work.

What may work is below code and an `before insert` context.

```
trigger OppLineItemScheduleTrigger on OpportunityLineItemSchedule (before insert) {
    Set<String> uniquePeriodNames = new Set<String>();

    for (OpportunityLineItemSchedule opportunityLineItemSchedule : Trigger.new) {
        uniquePeriodNames.add(opportunityLineItemSchedule.Period_Name__c);
    }

    List<ffrr__RecognitionPeriod__c> recognitionPeriods = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ffrr__RecognitionPeriod__c WHERE Name IN :uniquePeriodNames];

    Map<Name, Id> recognitionPeriodNameByIds = new Map<Name, Id>();

    for (ffrr__RecognitionPeriod__c ffrrRecognitionPeriod : recognitionPeriods) {
        recognitionPeriodNameByIds.put(ffrrRecognitionPeriod.Name, ffrrRecognitionPeriod.Id);
    }

    for (OpportunityLineItemSchedule olis : Trigger.new) {
        olis.Recognition_Period__c = recognitionPeriodNameByIds.get(olis.Period_Name__c);
    }
}
```